# SocketTimeout while running mapreduce job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, hdfs

We are getting some warnings in our mapreduce job while reading and writing data from datanode, it is not aborting the job though. This error comes up at several places in the job. Looks like an issue with timeout variables in hdfs-site.xml and hbase-site.xml files.

What timeout values should I change in these properties file and why?

Below is the extract from our log file. Any help would be of great help.

Read error:

```
filename: trace_log-2015_02_13.gz
extracted name: extractedLogtrace_log-2015_02_13.log
15/02/13 12:51:39 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
15/02/13 12:51:39 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop     library
15/02/13 12:51:39 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
15/02/13 12:51:39 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201410072206_7921
15/02/13 12:51:40 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
15/02/13 12:51:42 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
15/02/13 12:52:00 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DFSOutputStream ResponseProcessor exception  for block blk_-2121649173137352050_631454java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 69000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for read. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/D1:2011 remote=/D1:2010]
at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.doIO(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:164)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:155)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:128)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readLong(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.DataTransferProtocol$PipelineAck.readFields(DataTransferProtocol.java:124)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$ResponseProcessor.run(DFSClient.java:3161)
15/02/13 12:52:00 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Error Recovery for     blk_-2121649173137352050_631454 bad datanode[0] D1:2010
15/02/13 12:52:00 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Error Recovery for block blk_-2121649173137352050_631454 in pipeline D1:2010, D2:2010, D0:2010: bad datanode D1:2010
```

Write error:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 480000 millis timeout while waiting for
channel to be ready for write. ch :
java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/D1:2010 remote=/
D1:2011] at
org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.waitForIO(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:246) at
org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketOutputStream.waitForWritable(SocketOutputStream.java:159) at
org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketOutputStream.transferToFully(SocketOutputStream.java:198) at
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockSender.sendChunks(BlockSender.java:392) at
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockSender.sendBlock(BlockSender.java:490) at
 org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataXceiver.readBlock(DataXceiver.java:202) at    org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataXceiver.run(DataXceiver.java:104)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: `[connected local=/D1:2011 remote=/D1:2010]`,`bad datanode D1:2010`.Are you sure your datanode at d1 is in correct state?

Comment: @amow Yes it is in correct state. If it was not, job would never get completed. This error comes up for several blocks at several times in the job and the job gets completed successfully.

Comment: As I recall one file in hdfs often have 3 replications and locate in different nodes.If one of your node is loss, your job will success too.

Comment: @amow i found a similar issue over the web - http://www.cprogramdevelop.com/4197156/ 
It seems to be an issue with dfs.socket.timeout value. But can't conclude what and where I should make changes. 
At one instance, it also seems to be an connectivity issue between ports on the datanode.

Comment: edited my question with more error details and probable error.